# Hide a typo letter in an image in a pdf file generated by LaTeX

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I have a typo legend in an image in my pdf file generated by LaTeX. There is an extra "t" at the end of the legend. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the correct image.
How can I remove that "t" in my pdf?

[image]

BTW, I have the correct legend generated by MATLAB (see below). Can I somehow replace the wrong legend with correct one through LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: You have more than just one typo there...

Comment: Essentially this is the same as [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/5764) (duplicate).

Comment: @Werner Please see the updated question

Comment: `Estimated...` not `Estiamated`. If you have "the correct" legend, why not just recreate the image entirely?

Comment: @Werner Unfortunately I don't have the code of the figure anymore. I am reproducing only the legend.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the linked post to put a `node` onto the imported image and then place the graphics into that node like you normally would `\includegraphics[..]{new_legend}`.

Comment: What sometimes works is to convert the `pdf` to an `eps` file, look for the string there. correct it, and convert back to `pdf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Acrobat (not the reader, but Pro) allows modifying elements in a pdf quite nicely.  However it's a proprietary software.

For a LaTeX hack, I would have tried it this way:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[width = 3in]{figure}%
    \hspace{-1.43in}%
    \raisebox{2.1in}{%
        \includegraphics[width = 1.31in]{legend}%
        \hspace{0.1in}}
\end{document}
```

...of course downloading your two images as png.  This gives:

[image]

As you see the white space outside the new legend is a bit disturbing.  So, there are several things you need to do to get things right for your pdf's.

1. trim your new legend from just outside the box.
2. change the lengths to suit your case.

It's a trial-and-error method-- somewhat tiresome... but works !